# Reading in from a file giving address rather than values

Tags: c, file-io

So I'm reading data from a file seperated by commas. For some reason the code isn't going through the entire file and it is only printing out one specific componentType.

Also for the numOfItems and price, i'm just getting the address being printed out rather than the values!

Here's my code:

```
typedef struct inventory {
    char *componentType;
    char *stockCode;
    int numOfItems;
    int price;
} inventory;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char str[255];
    FILE *invf= fopen("inventory.txt", "r");
    // creating an array of structs
    struct inventory inv[384];
    // counter for array position
    int counter = 0;
    while (fgets(str, 256, invf) != NULL){
       char *componentType = strtok(str, " ,");
       // the NULL means it will pick up where it left off
       char *stockCode = strtok(NULL, " ,");
       int *numOfItems = strtok(NULL, " ,");
       int *price = strtok(NULL, " ,");

       // adding to the struct
       inv[counter].componentType = componentType;
       inv[counter].stockCode = stockCode;
       inv[counter].numOfItems = &numOfItems;
       inv[counter].price = &price;
       counter++;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for(i =0; i <300; i++){
        printf("%s %s %d %d \n", inv[i].componentType, inv[i].stockCode, inv[i].numOfItems, inv[i].price);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

CSV example

```
  lightbulb, RES_16M, 711, 1, 16M
    lightbulb, RES_16Ms, 7112, 1, 16Mk
    card, CAP_2700pf, 75, 26, 2700pf
    card, CAP_2700pfs, 75, 262, 2700pff
    Current, ASDba,   0, 800, "doesn't follow trend"
    Current, TL741,  20, 12,  "doesn't either"
```

Comment: You might want to assign `strdup()`s of the pointers `strtok()` returns, rather than storing those pointers in your structs directly, since the `fgets()` will overwrite the contents.

Comment: You need to `atoi` or something similar to get an int from a string.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `int *numOfItems = strtok(NULL, " ,");`? Also, if your compiler doesn't yell at you for it, then it means it's improperly configured.

Comment: yeah I'm unsure, i got rid of the * but still getting the same errors @Medinoc

Comment: @user3667111: The return type of `strtok()` is `char*` and nothing else. If you want an integer from a string, you need to *parse* it with `strtol()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `componenType` is a pointer to character. Every time you read a line, you assign the pointer into the line to `componentType`. In the end, all inventory items point to the same location, which is the last value read. You must allocate storage for it using `malloc`, and then copy the value.

In the same way you make integer elements a *pointer* to a (string) variable. But you must get the *value*. Use `atoi()`.

Note further that `char str[255];` can contain 255 characters, but you ask `fgets` to read a maximum of 256 characters. You forget to allocate the terminating null character.

Don't forget to check that `counter < 384`.

---

**EDIT** (added guidance)

You are building an array with inventory items. You can currently read no more than 384 items, the size of the array. If the number of items can be "any number" then you need a more dynamic data structure. For now the array will suffice, but you must check the bounds are not exceeded when reading an inventory file.

Every time you read a lne, you break that line from left to right into information items. For items that are of type string you must allocate memory to hold the string data:

```
   inv[counter].componentType = malloc(strlen(componentType)+1);
   strcpy(inv[counter].componentType, componentType);
```

When reading numeric information, it s still as a string and you must convert that to an integer:

```
   int numOfItems = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ,"));
```

or:

```
  inv[counter].numOfItems = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ,"));
```

After building the array in this way you can use it in your program. To change a component type, for example:

```
   free(inv[counter].componentType );                               // release old memory
   inv[counter].componentType = malloc(strlen(newComponentType)+1); // get new
   strcpy(inv[counter].componentType, newComponentType);
```

Once your are done, you should release all memory allocated with `malloc` by calling `free` for each item.

Comment: Thank you for trying to clear it up for me, still struggling a little.. only began learning C this week, so each bit of data needs to be dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: Works perfectly thank you, why is it not necessary to copy the int values?

Comment: `strtok` gives you a pointer into `str`. You expect that to represent a number in ASCII. You give that pointer to `atoi`. `atoi` converts it to an int. You assign that int as in one of the two examples I gave you (at the current place of your `strtok' call).